# PhpMailer giving certificate authentication error

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am using PhpMailer to send mails via my PHP code, but it gives me this certificate authentication error, though it started to send the mails when I changed host name, but still the error persists.

Comment: Your image does not show a certificate error. Can you show us the code (removing addresses etc..) along with any any error messages so we can help further. I would also advise removing the image as it's not that helpful and we can all see your personal email address and phone number within the URL parameters.

Comment: Don't post images of errors that are text - just post the text that shows the actual error. The image also contained an easily-decoded password, so I removed the image and suggest you change your password.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, and the only solution (at the moment) I found is to disable some of the SMTP options. It appears that the new PHPMailer is asking for certifications if PHP version is 5.6 or higher(or just 5.6, can't remember exactly). The code I used to fix it is:

```
$mail = new \PHPMailer(true);
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->isHTML();
$mail->Host = ...//my config
$mail->Port = ...//my port
$mail->isSMTP();
if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.6.0') >= 0) {
    $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
        'ssl' => array(
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'verify_peer_name' => false,
            'allow_self_signed' => true
        )
    );
}
```

I hope this helps you.